# How to copy List to Array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, containers

I have list of Guid's

```
List<Guid> MyList;
```

I need to copy its contents to Array

```
Guid[]
```

Please recommend me a pretty solution

Comment: Another question,

MyClass
{
Guid value;
}

List<MyClass>

How to copy Guid property to array of Guid's?

I mean not using iteration statement

Comment: I'm not 100% on SO etiquette, but it might be best to ask a new question as a new question. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As [Luke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55847/luke) said in comments, the particular `List<T>` type already has a `ToArray()` method. But if you're using C# 3.0, you can leverage the [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) extension method on any `IEnumerable` instance (that includes `IList`, `IList<T>`, collections, other arrays, etc.)

```
var myList = new List<Guid> {Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid()};
Guid[] array = myList.ToArray(); // instance method

IList<Guid> myList2 = new List<Guid> {Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid()};
Guid[] array2 = myList2.ToArray(); // extension method

var myList3 = new Collection<Guid> {Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid()};
Guid[] array3 = myList3.ToArray(); // extension method
```

Regarding your second question:

You can use the [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) method to perform the needed projection:

```
var list = new List<MyClass> {new MyClass(), new MyClass()};
Guid[] array = list.Select(mc => mc.value).ToArray();
```

Comment: `List<T>` has it's own (ie, not an extension) `ToArray` method, available since .NET2. (Exactly the same syntax as above, although you wouldn't be able to use `var` or object initialisers without C#3.)

Comment: @Luke: Very good point! I updated my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

You should just have to call MyList.ToArray() to get an array of the elements.

Answer (score 5):

The new way (using extensions or the ToArray() method on generic lists in .Net 2.0):

```
Guid[] guidArray = MyList.ToArray();
```

The old way:

```
Guid[] guidArray = new guidArray[MyList.Length];
int idx = 0;
foreach (var guid in MyList)
{
    guidArray[idx++] = guid;
}
```

Comment: C# 2.0 has `List.ToArray`, which uses `System.Array.Copy`

Answer (score 5):

Yet another option, in addition to `Guid[] MyArray = MyList.ToArray()`:

```
Guid[] MyArray = new Guid[MyList.Count]; // or wherever you get your array from
MyList.CopyTo(MyArray, 0);
```

This solution might be better if, for whatever reason, you already have a properly-sized array and simply want to populate it (rather than construct a new one, as `List<T>.ToArray()` does).

Answer (score 3):

Using the [Enumerable.ToArray() Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) you can do:

```
var guidArray = MyList.ToArray();
```

If you're still using C# 2.0 you can use the [List.ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x303t819%28VS.80%29.aspx) method. The syntax is the same (except there's no `var` keyword in C# 2.0).