# .NET Syntax For Implementing An Array

Tags: c#, .net, interface, interface-implementation

What is the syntax for implementing an  array of an interface?
iWord is an interface.

This is the syntax for List

```
public class Words : List<iWord>
{

}
```

But this fails
With an error message invalid base type
Am I getting an error because I am asking for something stupid?

```
public class Words : iWord[]
{

}
```

Comment: You cannot do that, maybe `IEnumerable<iWord>` will do? What do you want to achive?

Comment: @walkhard Basically IEnumerable and I will just add an indexer(this).    I will give it a try.  If you want to mark that as an answer I will accept.

Comment: Why not work with List<> and then turn it into array if needed? I find lists much easier to manipulate than arrays.

Comment: @Blam to put it into better words. Array's are part of the language itself and not written as part of the framework like a List or Stack or some other data structure. Any type that exists you could put a `[]` against it and now you've got an array of that type. So as a result you don't need to implement an array. Here is a question : **What would you put into your words class?**

Comment: @bobek Because under the covers is it an array as that is better suited for what I need than List

Comment: @gideon I just need to expose an enumerator and a this.

Comment: @Blam you'll get all of that when you inherit from `List` if you want it readonly then there are readonly lists too.

Comment: @gideon Under the covers is it an Array and I use it as an Array.  Yes I could expose an enumerator and indexer with about any collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that, but since arrays implements `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` maybe it'd be enough to

```
class Words : IEnumerable<iWord>
```

or you can just stick with your initial idea, after all `List` has an indexer:

```
class Words : List<iWord>
// use indexer to get first element
var myWords = new Words();
var first = myWords[0];
```

Comment: Because under the covers I need Array.Copy Method (Array, Int32, Array, Int32, Int32).  To the outside world only need to expose IEnumerable and indexer.

Comment: If you really need to expose array to the outside word you can use `ToArray()` method. You can also take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1921701/how-to-copy-list-to-array).

Comment: See my comment "To the outside world only need (want) to expose IEnumerable and a (read only) indexer".  Under the covers I do not want to use a List.  Under the covers I need an array and that is what I have.  I used List as a syntax example that did not throw an error - not because I wanted to expose a list.  IEnumerable with with a read only indexer is exactly what I need.